# why is certbot throwing an error when it looks to be getting the right response?

Tags: nginx, certbot

This:

```
certbot --nginx -d bigimprov.org.uk -d www.bigimprov.org.uk
```

produces:

> Domain: bigimprov.org.uk
> Type:   unauthorized
> Detail: Invalid
> response from http://www.bigimprov.org.uk    [185.157.233.135]:
> "\n<html    lang="en">\n\n\nThe Bradford
> Improv Group. Classes,    Shows, Comedy, Drama. Meet new people, try n"

I'm stumped. Surely that's exactly what should be coming back from a http request? Why is certbot choking?

Comment: Usually certbot is looking for a response in `/.well-known/acme-challenge`. Maybe your configuration is responding with `index.html` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Misconfiguration by the domain registrar.